# HTML5 game Phaser.io make weapon fire in sprite direction

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

I'm trying to make a little game with phaser.io and I have a little problem.

I use the weapon object of Phaser to make my hero fire bullets.

It's working good except when I turn on the left, the weapon keeps firing right.

Here's my code (in typescript) :

```
this.weapon = game.add.weapon(1500, 'shot');
this.weapon.bulletKillType = Phaser.Weapon.KILL_WORLD_BOUNDS;
this.weapon.bulletSpeed = 750;
this.weapon.fireRate = 2;
this.weapon.bulletAngleVariance = 3;
this.weapon.trackSprite(this, 0, 0, true);
```

Here's the move function :

```
walk = (direction) => {

    var speed;
    if (this.isGrounded) {
        speed = this.accel;
    } else {
        speed = this.airAccel;
    }
    if (direction == "right") {
        if (this.body.velocity.x < this.maxSpeed) {
            this.body.velocity.x += speed;
            this.animations.play('walk', 9, true);
            this.scale.x = 1;
        }

    } else if (direction == "left") {
        if (this.body.velocity.x > -this.maxSpeed) {
            this.body.velocity.x -= speed;
            this.animations.play('walk', 9, true);
            this.scale.x = -1;
        }
    }
}
```

and the fire event:

```
if (this.gamepad.justPressed(Phaser.Gamepad.XBOX360_X)) {
    this.weapon.fire(null);
}
```

I'm a noob with Phaser, so if you see something strange in my code, please tell me, I want to learn ;-)

Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: I don't see a single line of typescript here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change weapon.fireAngle according to your moving direction.

```
if (direction == "left")
{
    this.weapon.fireAngle = Phaser.ANGLE_LEFT;
}
else if (direction == "right")
{
    this.weapon.fireAngle = Phaser.ANGLE_RIGHT;
}
```